# Why pivot table does not show identical rows from the initial table?

Tags: excel, duplicates, pivot-table, rows

Why pivot table does not show identical rows from the initial table? My expectation is that the pivot table could show these in separate rows.

The initial table has 100 rows and my pivot table (while taking 4 columns) showing less.

To be more specific: All cells in 3 columns out of 4 are formatted as text, 1 column as number. If there are two rows which are identical in all 4 columns why only one of these is shown in the end pivot table? The number column is not summarized.

Answer (score 0):

Identical values in the rows of a pivot table will be rolled up into one row. If the number is in the values area of the pivot table, it will be summarized.

See this data example:

[image]

If the number column is in the Values of the pivot table, then the data gets summarised and only three rows of text are showing. It is entirely possible to rename the column title from "Sum of ..." to something else, so it may not be apparent that the data is summarised.

[image]

If you want to show all data, then put the number column into the rows area. You can then format the pivot table to repeat all item labels if you want to see the text for all rows.

[image]

Edit: If all values in the Rows area identical, then the data will be rolled up, too. A pivot table is about summarizing data. You'd typically have something in the values area that calculates something about this unique combination of four values.

[image]

If you want to show all duplicates, you need to enter a unique 5th column in the row area.

Comment: Okay. Lets take your example. The number in the 2nd and the 5th row should be identical. Try 0 or any other number. Furthermore I have all 4 columns in the rows area. Does it show all?